# Handling massive amounts of repeated tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

We started of with a project using tests for Validators, Formatting, Visibility, etc. 
At the start we had a pretty large amount of tests for one country but as we started adding new implementations for new countries we started to run into a bit of a manageability problem.

Adding a test for a new country; we copied the implementation from the previous country. As time goes by, new fields got added/removed, certain countries ignore things, other ones require extra stuff, it seems like everything is out of control and out of sync. We may have coverage holes on certain implementations or dupes (although I managed to find dupes using nCrunch)

We are using nUnit Tests. This is an example of a medium ranged test. We have several massive blocks per country, over 15 countries now and growing. Its about  5000 single tests just for validation metadata.

[image]

I have been trying to work out a way to use inheritance? Or some kind of base framework.. example, define the tests once but have an easy way to modify the expected outcomes. Finding a test to update is a mission now and results in updating the wrong test because of multiple coverage.

Any advice?

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more information on how your tests vary per country. I think what you need is to look at `TestCaseSource`, but you may also want to look at some of the combinatorial attributes or `TestFixtureSource` depending on how you are combining country data with all of those other test parameters.

Comment: We just copy and paste the tests into a new file and amend the tests as needed for the specific country. tbh im pretty newb at tests and nunit but this is becoming a monster now.

Comment: As you have found, that quickly becomes unmaintainable. How different are your tests for each country? Can you wrap the differences in lamdas and inject them into your tests?